# Check for binary string length?

Tags: php

Is there a native or inexpensive way to check for the length of a string in bytes in PHP?

Comment: Do you have an example of your data? Because if it really is just a string, I don't think you have any alternatives to strlen().

Comment: @sunetos It's a string containing 16 bytes of binary data, to plug into a BINARY field in MySQL. It's not a character-encoded string of ones and zeros or anything like that, if that clarifies it any. If you print the string you get gibberish. What I want to do is check for 16 bytes of data.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

The length of a string (textual data) is determined by the position of the NULL character which marks the end.
In case of binary data, NULL can be and often is in the middle of data.

You don't check the length of binary data. You have to know it beforehand. In your case, the length is 16 (bytes, not bits, if it is UUID).

As far as UUID validity is concerned, any 16-byte value is a valid UUID, so you are out of luck there.

Comment: This is incorrect. It would be correct if PHP were treating strings like C does, but it apparently had some forethought on this exact problem.

Answer (score 21):

See http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/653733-binary-string-length

Relevant part:

> > "*In PHP, like in C, the string ends with a zero-character, '\0', (char)
> >     0, null-terminator, null-byte or whatever you like to call it*."
>
> No, that's not the case - PHP strings are stored with both the length and the
>   data, unlike C strings that just has one pointer and uses a terminator. They're
>   "binary-safe" - NUL doesn't terminate the string.
>
> See the definition of zvalue_value in zend.h; the string part has both a "char
>   *val" and "int len".
>
> Problems would start if you're using the mbstring.func_overload, which changes
>   how strlen() and the other functions work, and does try and treat strings as
>   strings of characters in a specific encoding rather than a string of bytes.
>   This is not the normal PHP behaviour.

The answer is that strlen should return the number of bytes regardless of the content of the string. For multi-byte character strings, you get the wrong number of characters, but the right number of bytes. However, you need to be certain you're not using the mbstring overload, which changes how strlen behaves.

Answer (score 5):

In the event that you have mbstring overload set or your are developing for the platforms where you are unsure about this setting you can do the following:

```
$len=strlen(bin2hex($data))/2;
```

The reason why this works is that in Hex you are guaranteed to get 2 characters for all bytes that come from `bin2hex` (it returns two chars even for the initial binary 0).

Note that it will use significantly more resources than a normal `strlen` (afterall, so you should definitely not do that to the large amount of data if it's not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php). This function returns the length of any string in bytes. It's binary-safe and is O(1).

---

Be careful if you are still using PHP 7 as it could have the `mbstring.func_overload` enabled which would then return the length in Unicode characters. This setting is now gone and the function is safe to use on all environments.